# how to find cost based on number of characters in a textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have a textarea in my form

```
<textarea id="word_count"></textarea>
Cost <input type="text" value=""/>
```

I used to find the cost based on number of characters the user enters in the textbox. $50 for each 200 characters. result would be like this

```
cost = $50 for 200 character 
       $100 for 400 character
       $150 for 600 character
```

I found the number of characters entering in the textbox.

```
<script>
  $("#word_count").on('keyup', function() {
    var word_count  =$("#word_count").val().replace(/\s/g, "").length;     
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Where you're facing problem ?

Comment: Isn't it a simple if condition?

Comment: i think afor loop is needed. the user can type as many characters

Comment: nnned to increase the cost by $50 for every 200 characters.

Comment: So for less than 200 characters the price is free..?

Answer (score 2):

```js
let characterCount = 650;

let price = Math.floor(characterCount / 200) * 50;
console.log (price);
```

Answer (score -1):

Prepare a helper json like:
var helperJSON ={
200:'$50',
400: '$100',
600: '$150'
}

```
$("#word_count").on('keyup', function() {
        var word_count=$("#word_count").val().replace(/\s/g, "").length;  
        var cost = helperJSON[word_count];
        if(cost){
          //do something
        }


    });
```

SO when you capture the characters call the helper variable which will give you the costs.